# Doubt regarding a limit which is related to MVT

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

Let the function $f(x)$ be differentiable  and $f'(x)$ be continuous in $\left(-\infty,\infty \right)$ with $f'(2)=14$ then evaluate the limit

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(2+\sin x)-f(2+x\cos x)}{x-\sin x}$$

My attempt:

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(2+\sin x)-f(2+x\cos x)}{x-\sin x}$

$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{f(2+\sin x)-f(2+x\cos x)}{\sin x-x\cos x}\right)$ $\frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{x-\sin x}$$=\left(f'(2)\right)(2)=28$

Is the method used here correct

Comment: In my opinion, your work is too brief. It's hard to say whether your attempt is correct or not. You need to elaborate on them if this is homework. E.g. why is the limit of the first multiplicand equal to $f'(2)$? Note that it's not a usual two-sided derivative. If $f$ is twice differentiable, we can handle it easily using Taylor's theorem, but $f$ is only $C^1$ here. You may also need to apply L'Hospital rule to justify the limit of the second multiplicand. (By the way, where did you apply MVT? I can't see it.)

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I know how MVT *can be* applied. What I was saying is that the OP hasn't justified how that differential quotient is equal to $f'(2)$, using MVT or not. They need to show the details.

Comment: @user1551: ok got it. Will delete comment.

Comment: I was not saying that I have used mvt. What I was trying to say that maybe we can solve this problem using mvt also

Answer (score 2):

Your method is correct, but you need additional work to show that $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x - x\cos x}{x - \sin x} = 2$$ A possible approach is to use L'Hospital's Rule or Taylor series. Also you should write that fraction $$\frac{f(2 + \sin x) - f(2 + x\cos x)}{\sin x - x\cos x}$$ is equal to $f'(c_{x})$ by mean value theorem where $c_{x}$ lies between $2 + \sin x$ and $2 + x\cos x$ and as $x \to 0$ the number $c_{x} \to 2$. By continuity of $f'$ the fraction tends to $f'(2)$.