# Evaluate given limit

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let the function $f(x)$ be differentiable  and $f'(x)$ be continuous in $\left(-\infty,\infty \right)$ with $f'(2)=14$ then evaluate the limit

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(2+\sin x)-f(2+x\cos x)}{x-\sin x}$

My attempt:

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(2+\sin x)-f(2+x\cos x)}{x-\sin x}$

$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{f(2+\sin x)-f(2+x\cos x)}{\sin x-x\cos x}\right)$ $\frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{x-\sin x}$$=\left(f'(2)\right)(2)=28$

Is the method used here correct

Comment: How did you get the value of the limits of both factors in the last line? I think you should at least explain that.

Comment: Your result is correct. I assume you used that first factor approaches to $f'(2)$, when x approaches to $0$ and the limit of the second factor you probably calculated by using L'hopitals rule. Although, you should write your work down, as DonAntonio suggested.

Comment: Since, it is in an indeterminate form, you can use L'hopital rule, which in this case you will use it twice.

Comment: It is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1870604/72031